# How to generate an evenly-spaced series of rational numbers in Python?

Tags: python, loops, generate-series

I'm looking for a clean way (list comprehension?) to generate an evenly-spaced list in vanilla Python (no numpy available), e.g. in perl I might do this:

```
my @a=();
for ($i=2.765; $i<30.2; $i+=1.07537) {
    push @a, $i
}
```

The only way I've found to do this in Python involves a while loop, but I was hoping there was a cleaner, more concise way.

Comment: (Closed as duplicate but the referenced page doesn't answer this question...)

Comment: So what does your above code do? What's the expect output?

Comment: @Bryan: then edit your question to clarify the difference.